# How to implement an interactive map with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to build a web page with a map of a state as its background. When the mouse hovers over a city, a small window pops up near the mouse pointer and shows some information about this city.

I cannot remember any websites that has implemented this feature. A similar example is the Google map, however, the user needs to click on a location in order to show that location's information.

Anyone know such kind of web pages? How can I built such a web page?

Comment: You can use Google Maps (https://developers.google.com/maps/?hl=it), leaflet (http://leafletjs.com/), or other map serverices or create your own simplified version

Comment: use d3.js, it is free. http://datamaps.github.io/

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa  d3.js is amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I however would recommend you leaflet:
www.leafletjs.com

Leaflet is the most popular js map library nowadays. If you know how to use JS, you will have no troubles unsing leaflet. Its very well documented.
Here are some leaflet tutorials:
http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html

Answer (score 0):

I,d use google maps and it's infowindow features,

a quick start will look like this;

```
    <!--load the api in your html side-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&language=es&region=ES"></script> 

    <!--place a map canvas with a selector inside your <body> tags-->
    <div id="gmap_div" style="width:400px;height:400px;"></div>

    <!-- then initialize it and work with the map object; -->
    <body onload="initialize()">

/* the javascript */

        function initialize() {


                mapOptions = {
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.41678, -3.70379),
                  zoom: 12,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_div"),
                    mapOptions);

            }
```

Thats a start with gmaps, then its not hard create windows or attach events to it.

You'll find all the gmap documentation here:

[https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/?hl=en][1]